# Structs inside of structs in C

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef char tCadena[TCAD];
typedef struct{
    int i; 
    int f;
    tCadena cola[TCOL];
}tCola;
typedef struct{
    tCadena nombre[TCAD];
    int numfich;
    tCola cola;
}tImpresora;
typedef struct{
    tImpresora impresora;
    int ocupado;
}tElementoImpresora;
typedef tElementoImpresora tablaImp[MAXIMP];
```

So I have these structs, and I have a variable called `thing` of type `tablaImp` 
I want to go inside the struct and set the `i` of the **first** structure to `0`.
I tried with:

```
tablaImp thing;
thing.impresora.cola.i=0;
```

But it tells me that its not a part of the structure. 
How can I do to go inside the **first** structure ? Thanks.

Comment: How is `c` declared?

Comment: Sorry, i used it on a function and forgot to change it, it is: thing.impresora.cola.i=0

Answer (score 5):

`tablaImp` is an array, you need to index it.

```
for (i = 0; i < MAXIMP; i++) {
    thing[i].impresora.cola.i = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`thing` is an array (of structs), and you're trying to use it as if it were a struct:

```
typedef tElementoImpresora tablaImp[MAXIMP];
tablaImp thing;
thing.impresora.cola.i=0;
/*   ↑ need an array index here */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef tElementoImpresora tablaImp[MAXIMP];
tablaImp thing;
thing.impresora.cola.i=0;
```

`thing` is an array, you need to specify the array element:

```
thing[0].impresora.cola.i = 0
```

Comment: Lots of random downvoting today. :-( Have a (+1) for the good answer.

Comment: @NPE Not only today. SO is trying to keep its high standards, but I think they are doing it wrong :( Just because someone doesn't understand something (and naturally asks it here) he gets downvoted cause of wrong formatting or/and bad composed question....